# MaaS distributes new ip on every reboot

Tags: server, juju, maas

I have a working installation of MaaS in Version 1.5 on Trusty.
I've deployed a juju bootstrap node already through it and have some 15 other physical machines in ready state.
I've successfully deployed juju-gui on the bootstrap node and all is well. I just figured, though, that I have a problem with the IPs.
I had to reboot the bootstrap node, after that it was unavailable. That's because MaaS provided the system with a new IP from the dhcp pool. It does this, on every reboot, thought the system is allocated to a user.

Did I miss any config entries?
I didn't have this behavior on MaaS 1.4 on precise. So I'm a little surprised by this.
At this moment, I cannot make progress with the roll out of the Cluster through juju, as juju-core is unable to contact the bootstrap node.

Comment: I've seen that in _/var/lib/maas/dhcp/dhcpd.leases_ not all nodes in ready state do have a host block with a static entry. I added one for the IP that I need for the machine in question and run _dhclient_ again. I hope this will stick for now, though the source for the issue remains unknown.

Answer (score 4):

OP posted:

> I've seen that in `/var/lib/maas/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` not all nodes in ready state do have a host block with a static entry. I added one for the IP that I need for the machine in question and run dhclient again. I hope this will stick for now, though the source for the issue remains unknown.